# How to Create Queries According to Certain Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is a value
a = 8

and a table like below

| Column A |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

How to create queries using SQL in order to make a table like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 |

The last row for column B filled 1 because of the result of this one
8-(3+4). For first two rows it is filled 3 and 4 because
3 is less than 8, 4 is less than 8. So the column B is the part of formula that generates 8.

Comment: please explain verbally how formula works, which 3 and 4 coming from. and how calculate column b first and second rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Can you add a few more rows of sample data, and update the result accordningly.

Comment: Is there a column to order by as well? (ID, timestamp or similar.)

Answer (score 0):

still not clear what you try to achieve. but this example return exactly what you requesting (base on parameterA = 8)

```
declare @t table (ColumnA int)
declare @a int = 8

insert into @t (ColumnA) values
(3),(4),(5)



;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT SUM(ColumnA) asum, ColumnA 
   FROM @t
   Group by ColumnA
), cteRanked AS
(
   SELECT asum, ColumnA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnA) rownum
   FROM cte
) 
SELECT 
  c1.ColumnA,
  ColumnB = case 
        when ((SELECT SUM(asum) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum) < @a) then ColumnA
        Else @a - (SELECT SUM(asum) FROM cteRanked c2 WHERE c2.rownum <= c1.rownum) + ColumnA
        end
FROM cteRanked c1;
```

[image]

Comment: read about table variables, common table expressions, grouping, row_num function, and Cumulative Sum

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and other readers which dbms this is for.

Comment: i would assume it is for t-sql MSSQL since there are related tags

Comment: Of course, the <sql-server> tag was added 3 hours after my comment. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM(a) window function to calculate the running sum. Then use a case expression to get the b values.

```
select a, case when rs <= 8 then a
               when rs - a <= 8 then 8 - rs + a
               else 0
          end as b
from
(
    select id, a, sum(a) over (order by id) rs
    from t
) dt
```

Demo at: https://dbfiddle.uk/5jsBmWul